# oracle user rowtype variable to insert into table using execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowtype

I'm using Oracle 11g.
I have a function which I want to use to insert into a row into a table.
One of the parameters is a table%rowtype. This is already populated with most of the correct data.
One of the parameters is a varchar2 representing the target table name.
I want to change the values in three columns in the variable of type table%rowtype, then insert it into the table named by the input variable of type varchar2.

```
  FUNCTION AddMP(vMP          IN MEASUREPOINT%ROWTYPE,
                  vNewPointNum IN MEASUREPOINT.POINTNUM%TYPE,
                 v_CalMtrName IN MEASUREPOINT.METERNAME%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      v_RetVal       VARCHAR2(50) := K_OKAY;
      v_Status       VARCHAR2(50) := NULL;
      v_AssetNum     MEASUREPOINT.ASSETNUM%TYPE;
      v_SiteId       MEASUREPOINT.SITEID%TYPE;
      v_OrgId        ASSETMETER.ORGID%TYPE;
      v_ChangeDate   ASSETMETER.CHANGEDATE%TYPE;
      v_err_num      NUMBER;
      v_err_msg      VARCHAR2(255);
      v_err_string   VARCHAR2(1000) := NULL;
      v_insert_str   VARCHAR2(2000) := NULL;
      v_RowsAffected VARCHAR2(10) := NULL;
      v_NewMP        MEASUREPOINT%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      v_AssetNum   := vMP.Assetnum;
      v_SiteId     := vMP.Siteid;
      v_ChangeDate := SYSDATE;
      v_OrgId      := vMP.Orgid;
      --Put new data into vMP

      tempMP                := vMP;
      tempMP.Pointnum       := vNewPointNum;
      tempMP.Metername      := v_CalMtrName;
      tempMP.Measurepointid := measurepointseq.nextval;
      tempMP.Pointnum       := vNewPointNum;

      /*      v_insert_str := ' insert \*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tab, tab_pk) *\into ' ||
                            TABLE_MEASUREPOINT || ' values :insertRecord ';
      */
          v_insert_str := ' insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tab, tab_pk)     */into ' ||
                          TABLE_MEASUREPOINT || ' values tempMP ';

          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_insert_str;
          /*INSERT INTO MEASUREPOINT_TEMP VALUES tempMP;*/
```

I am getting various errors, but I suspect I actually have to enumerate all the target columns and their individual values. I would really like to not do this, but use the input variable instead after fixing three values.
Is it even possible to do this?
thanks in any case
Jeff

Comment: It would be helpful if you told use what the errors were, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column names of table `MEASUREPOINT` you can do this. Assuming columns are (col1,col2), then your insert will be:

```
v_insert_str := ' insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tab, tab_pk)     */into ' ||
            TABLE_MEASUREPOINT || ' values ('||tempMP.col1||','||tempMP.col2||')';
```

Comment: If you're going to use this approach, you should really use `dbms_assert.enquote_literal` to add quotes to the concatenated values.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the rowtype variable into the dynamic SQL, you should use a bind variable and `using`:

```
v_insert_str := ' insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tab, tab_pk)     */into ' ||
                          TABLE_MEASUREPOINT || ' values :1 ';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_insert_str using tempMP;
```

The reason your original approaches did not work is that dynamic SQL run via `execute immediate` runs in it's own scope, outside of the scope of the procedure or block. In order to use local variables in the `execute immediate`, you must either pass them in using bind variable (as in my answer) or concatenate them (as in @Aramillo's answer). Generally, it's better to bind, if you can.

Comment: Wouldn't this raise "expressions have to be of SQL types" error? I have a very similar issue and I get it.